# What are the default cookies used by NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, cookies

I am developing a NodeJS application. I do not explicitly use cookies in my code. However, even running my application locally using nodemon, I notice that the page is using cookies. The names of these cookies are:

```
_iub_cs-61800697
_ga_6K6RYGK3ZD
_ga
```

I am curious about where these come from. I assume that somewhere in the NodeJS code these are being created. So my questions are:

1. Are these indeed default cookies that NodeJS is creating?
2. What purpose do they serve?
3. Are they required? That is, if a user has cookies disabled, will this adversely affect the function of my application?
4. Am I obligated (under GDPR regulations or other) to let the user know my site uses cookies and give them an option to manage them?

General information about the default cookies set up using other technologies would also be appreciated. In particular, I intend to host this site on AWS, so it is possible other cookies might be generated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Node.js doesn't create cookies. The `_ga` ones are from Google Analytics, the `_iub` one looks to be from a company called [Iubenda](https://www.iubenda.com/en/). It's likely something in your HTML that's setting them, or perhaps a browser extension that you're using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

node itself doesn't implicitly set any cookies, it could be due to an integration (the _ga ones are set by google, and are often there due to including cient-side javascript for google [analytics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/cookie-usage) or [recaptcha](https://www.iubenda.com/en/help/23902-google-recaptcha-gdpr-how-to-be-compliant)).

Comment: Thanks. On further investigation, I have found that these cookies only appear in Chrome. Nothing comes up in Edge or Firefox, so I guess it is a Google thing.